# Trying to supress #N/A on a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Currently using a sheet to track mileage to and from sites. The column that pulls the miles is using the the following. It throws a #N/A and I would like to suppress this so that I can see a running total of mileage.

`=IF(K34="Yes",INDEX(Matrix,MATCH(C34,Input2,0),MATCH(D34,Input1,0))*2,INDEX(Matrix,MATCH(C34,Input2,0),MATCH(D34,Input1,0)))`

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it would be easier to use the `IFERROR` function:

```
=IFERROR(IF(K34="Yes",INDEX(Matrix,MATCH(C34,Input2,0),MATCH(D34,Input1,0))*2,INDEX(Matrix,MATCH(C34,Input2,0),MATCH(D34,Input1,0))),)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the ISNA() function

```
=IF(ISNA(IF(K34="Yes",INDEX(Matrix,MATCH(C34,Input2,0),MATCH(D34,Input1,0))*2,INDEX(Matrix,MATCH(C34,Input2,0),MATCH(D34,Input1,0))), "", IF(K34="Yes",INDEX(Matrix,MATCH(C34,Input2,0),MATCH(D34,Input1,0))*2,INDEX(Matrix,MATCH(C34,Input2,0),MATCH(D34,Input1,0))))
```

Disclaimer, I was unable to test since I do not have a copy of your sheet

Here is an example I wrote for handling NA from the QUERY() function

```
=if(isna(query($A$1:$C, "SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE B ='"&F2&"' LABEL COUNT(B) ''",1)),0,query($A$1:$C, "SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE B ='"&F2&"' LABEL COUNT(B) ''",1))
```

Comment: Here's a copy of the sheet. I couldn't get the ISNA() function to work.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZlA95Jnk1lVNPApWfkE9_SJJUYo7IvosBAWgOTZbcM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please make it share view only